# R - Problems with nodes() for a partykit tree

Tags: r, party

I have a similar question as in

[how to get all terminal nodes - weight & response prediction 'ctree' in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959431/how-to-get-all-terminal-nodes-weight-response-prediction-ctree-in-r)

I would like to get the result like this. Nevertheless, the nodes()-function does not work properly in my case. And I do not understand why.

```
tree <- ctree(DV ~ IV, data = data)

nodes(tree, unique(where(tree)))
```

When I run it, I allways get the following error:

```
Error in match.arg(data, choices = c("all", "organization", "endpoint",  : 
  'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

What can I do in order to make the function work?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you please state what information you want to extract exactly? The `nodes()` and `where()` functions from `party` are not available in `partykit`. Instead a cleaner and more standard interface has been set up, e.g., you can easily subset trees with the `[` operator etc. Hence, if you say what you want to extract, we can easily provide guidance on how to do so in `partykit`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `ctree` function of the `party` package:

```
library(party)
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x+runif(100)
data <- data.frame(DV=y , IV=x)

tree <- party::ctree(DV ~ IV, data = data)
nodes(tree, unique(where(tree))) 

# [[1]]
# 3)*  weights = 19 

# [[2]]
# 6)*  weights = 26 

# [[3]]
# 9)*  weights = 19 

# [[4]]
# 8)*  weights = 19 

# [[5]]
# 5)*  weights = 17
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the code `nodes(tree, unique(where(tree)))` pertains to the old `party` as opposed to the new `partykit` package. However, transitioning to the newer `partykit` interface is highly recommended so I wouldn't recommend to downgrade to `party` just for using this old code snippet.